# How to pass one state the component father to component child to open a modal React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have a component to create account, but i need edit this accounts by a modal, i tried this way

```
function ListaContas (){
    const Contas = useSelector((state) => state.contas)
    const [editarConta, setEditarConta] = useState(false)
    const [contaEdit, setContaEdit] = useState()
        
    const [contasSelected, setSelected] = useState([])
    
    function Editar(e){
       setEditarConta(true)
       
    }
    return (
        <Container  fluid>
            <MyModal open = {editarConta} /> // this is de modal component 
            <button type="button" onClick = { () => Editar()} class="btn btn-
        </Container>
    )
}    
export default ListaContas;
```

the child component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ModalTitle } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Modal from 'react-modal'

const MyModal = (props) => {
    const [OpenModal, setOpenModal] = useState(props.open)
    console.log(props.open)
    return(
      
           <Modal
            shouldCloseOnEsc = {true}
            isOpen = {OpenModal}
            onRequestClose = {setOpenModal(false)}
           >

           </Modal>
    
    )
}

export default MyModal;
```

When i call the modal component i get this error

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
> prevent an infinite loop.

What is the correct way to work with modal when the father component pass data to the child component manipulate and return to the father to close modal

@Problem solved
The problem in my code was that i didn't have a conditional to show my component modal, all the time the render was called, my component was re-renders.
I solved this adding a conditional like that

this

```
return (
        <Container  fluid>
            <MyModal open = {editarConta} /> // this is de modal component 
            <button type="button" onClick = { () => Editar()} class="btn btn-
        </Container>
    )
```

to this

```
//Father component
return (
    <Container  fluid>
        {editarConta && <LancarConta open = {editarConta} />} // this is de modal component 
        <button type="button" onClick = { () => Editar()} class="btn btn-
    </Container>
)
//Child component
const MyModal = (props) => {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(props.open)
    console.log(props.open)
    function CloseModal(){
        window.location.reload()
        setModal(false)
    }
    return(
        <Modal
            isOpen = {modal}
            onRequestClose = {() => CloseModal()}
        >
        <div>
            <h1> teste</h1>
        </div>
        </Modal> 
   )
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setOpenModal(false)` on render.
You need send a anonymous function to onRequestClose:

```
const MyModal = (props) => {
    return (
        <Modal
            shouldCloseOnEsc = {true}
            isOpen = {props.open}
            onRequestClose = {() => setOpenModal(false)} // Change this line
        >
        
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the props as state in the MyModal Component.

```
const MyModal = (props) => {
    return(
      
           <Modal
            shouldCloseOnEsc = {true}
            isOpen = {props.open}
            onRequestClose = {props.closeModal}
           >

           </Modal>
    
    )
}

export default MyModal;
```

This should resolve the re-render issue.
Also then you should pass a closing method as props so you can use it `onRequestClose`. Preferably it shouldn't be a `setState` method as this could also trigger endless rerenders. The close modals Method should be in the parent component and look something like this:

```
    const closeModal = () => {
        setEdiarConta(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i get this, but i don't know how i'll call the component father again to set the props to false for hide de modal.

Comment: I see that the issues has been resolved. However, I think it still will be helpful to answer your comment. You create the closeModal method in the Father component (where the EdiarConta state is). You then pass the state and the closeModal method as props to the MyModal component. When you trigger the method from MyModal it executes the code in the Father component. When the state is set in the Father component, it will rerender and update the props with the new state value. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html this link might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, is better than the way i found to solve my problem.